# HoTT informal path induction

Tags: induction, homotopy-type-theory

As before I'm still exploring HoTT. While turning more to the informal everyday view on it, I have found an issue I cannot solve by my own.

Proving by *path induction* can be done formal by invoking the induction principle or even more technical: using the $\mathsf{ind}_=$ method. But it can be also done using the informal way. Consider, for example the associativity of path concatenation:

#### Associativity of Path Concatenation

For any $p : x = y$, $q : y = z$ and $r : z = w$ it holds that
$$
p \centerdot (q \centerdot r) = (p \centerdot q) \centerdot r
$$

where $\centerdot$ is the path concatenation.

In the HoTT Book there is an informal proof which is stated as follows:

#### *Proof*

By induction, it suffices to assume $p,q$ and $r$ are all $\mathsf{refl}_x$. But in this case, we have:
\begin{align*}
  p\centerdot (q\centerdot r) &\equiv\mathsf{refl}_x\centerdot(\mathsf{refl}_x\centerdot \mathsf{refl}_x)\\
&\equiv \mathsf{refl}_x\\
&\equiv (\mathsf{refl}_x\centerdot\mathsf{refl}_x)\centerdot\mathsf{refl}_x\\
&\equiv (p\centerdot q)\centerdot r
\end{align*}

#### What wonders me

So why not conclude $(q \centerdot r) \centerdot p$ here, for example, since every one of these are judgementally equal to $\mathsf{refl}_x$ in this particular case?

#### Own ideas

My guess is, that each $\mathsf{refl}_x$ is associated with $p,q,r$ resp. in some "syntactic sugar way" since after all this informal method is basically just an abbreviation for the formal way. But it looks quite fishy.

#### Questions

Would this be an explanation? And therefore: when proving informally with several path inductions it's best to keep track of which $\mathsf{refl}_x$ belongs to which path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you can't prove $p\cdot (q\cdot r) = (q\cdot r)\cdot p$ by path induction is that for *general* $p,q,r$, the statement is ill-typed.  It doesn't matter that it becomes well-typed and true after replacing all the paths by refl.  Path induction only applies to a statement that's well-typed in the general case, and becomes true when replacing the path(s) by refl.

Comment: What about something like, for any $p,q : x = y$, $p = q$?

Comment: @ToucanIan You have to do path induction one path at a time.  After path induction on $q$ (say), your statement becomes "for any $p:x=x$, $p=\mathsf{refl}_x$".  Now you can't do a further induction over $p$ because $p$ no longer has a general path-type but its two endpoints are constrained to be the same.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense.